# Geographic distribution of ‘I haven’t’ and ‘I’ve not’

Tags: english, dialects, frequency, dialect-mapping

The answer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68048/difference-between-i-havent-and-ive-not-etc) on English Language & Usage discusses a possible difference between American and British dialects in their use of ‘I’ve not’ and ‘I haven’t’. I have noticed ‘I’ve not’ used more in the west of England than in the east.

Is there any research about the relative frequency in different dialects or geographical distribution of ‘I haven’t’ and ‘I’ve not’?

Comment: I sometimes want to punch the Google N-grams for being in a form (contractions are expanded) that doesn't let one make these comparisons.

Comment: I don’t think there’s any great mystery to the geographic distribution of ‘I haven’t’ – as far as I know, it’s used _everywhere_ in the Anglosphere. ‘I’ve not’ has a more limited geographic distribution (at least as a common or primary variant – it too is a _possible_ variant everywhere), but not ‘I haven’t’.

Comment: Just curious, are you saying that e.g. "I've not been there" is more commonly used in the west of England than "I haven't been there"?

Comment: People in general do not seem to realize that the only way (until we're run completely by digital devices) to answer a question like this is via a survey. As it stand now, the best responses will be from individuals with the most widespread experience of English.

Comment: @AlexB. no, “I haven’t been there “ is still more common but “I’ve not been there” is unheard of in the east (in my experience).

Comment: I’ve noticed that a young colleague in London, from very near London, regularly uses “I’ve not” which I’d previously regarded as slightly archaic. He also, BTW, uses “I’ve” for possession, as in “I’ve a new TV” where I’d expect either “I’ve got…” or “I have”.

Comment: First, it's just one distinction among many. _I haven't_ versus _I don't have_ versus _I've not_. There are conditions and correlations for all of them. Second, nobody is consistent -- everybody uses several varieties. Third, _have_ as an auxiliary verb, or as part of an idiomatic construction like _have the car fixed_, or as a main verb meaning "possess" have different grammatical usages, and people have different grammatical habits of their use. As @Lambie points out, only a sociolinguistic survey will answer your question, and it won't be just geography, either.